# Ability to send a work-item (Epic, bug, user story etc) via email to an external user

Tags: azure, azure-devops, outlook, azure-boards

I have an Azure DevOps porject where we are collaborating internally with Azure-Boards.
We have some tasks/bugs that we share with external users i.e. vendors who do not have access to our Azure-Boards/project. We do not want them in there either.

Right now people are copy/pasting stuff from work items to email and then sending them to intended person. I am looking for something that can allow us to export work item content in an email client or just allow us to share one work item only via email.

Any tips or suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my test,  we could not email a work item to an external user account from Azure DevOps directly.

[image]

For your requirement, you could select the work items to be sent out in "Query" and then in Query" select "Export to CSV", you can download the excel of the work items and email the CSV excel to the intended person.

[image]

[image]

Hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: Doesnt really solve it but definitely another workaround. Thanks a lot